# Biodiesel Reactor Design with GEKKO on Python

Tags: python, optimization, gekko

I'm trying to model a biodiesel reactor on python using GEKKO, but I'm not getting obtain the correct temperature profile, the Manipulated Variable doesn't change the value as expected... Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO()

nt = 1001
m.time = np.linspace(0,100,nt)

# Parameters
T = m.MV(value=321,ub=338,lb=298)
T.STATUS = 1
T.DCOST = 0.01
T.DMAX = 20

# Variables
CTG = m.Var(value=0.3226)
CDG = m.Var(value=0)
CMG = m.Var(value=0)
CE = m.Var(value=0)
CA = m.Var(value=1.9356)
CG = m.Var(value=0)

p = np.zeros(nt)
p[-1] = 1.0
final = m.Param(value=p)

# Intermediates
k1 = m.Intermediate(3.92e7*m.exp(-6614.83/T))
k2 = m.Intermediate(5.77e5*m.exp(-4997.98/T))
k3 = m.Intermediate(5.88e12*m.exp(-9993.96/T))
k4 = m.Intermediate(0.98e10*m.exp(-7366.64/T))
k5 = m.Intermediate(5.35e3*m.exp(-3231.18/T))
k6 = m.Intermediate(2.15e4*m.exp(-4824.87/T))

# Equations
m.Equation(CTG.dt()== -k1*CTG*CA + k2*CDG*CE)
m.Equation(CDG.dt()== k1*CTG*CA - k2*CDG*CE - k3*CDG*CA + k4*CMG*CE)
m.Equation(CMG.dt()== k3*CDG*CA - k4*CMG*CE - k5*CMG*CA + k6*CG*CE)
m.Equation(CE.dt()== k1*CTG*CA - k2*CDG*CE + k3*CDG*CA - k4*CMG*CE + k5*CMG*CA - k6*CG*CE)
m.Equation(CA.dt()== -CE.dt())
m.Equation(CG.dt()== k5*CMG*CA - k6*CG*CE)

# Objective Function
m.Maximize(CE*final)


m.options.IMODE = 9
m.solve()

print('Objective: ' + str(CE[-1]))

plt.figure(1)

plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(m.time,CE.value,'k:',lw=2,label=r'$C_E$')
plt.plot(m.time,CTG.value,'b-',lw=2,label=r'$C_TG$')
plt.plot(m.time,CA.value,'g-',lw=2,label=r'$C_A$')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.legend(loc='best')

plt.figure(2)

plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(m.time,T.value,'r--',lw=2,label=r'$Temp$')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Value')

plt.show()
```

I need to obtain a temperature profile like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A sensitivity study reveals that the optimal solution is to maximize the temperature. The problem with the code in your question is the selection of `IMODE=9`. Use `IMODE=6` with less time points for a more reliable solution. The sequential optimization mode (9) is not as reliable as the simulataneous mode (6).

Here is a simulation at different temperatures with the temperature status off.

```py
T.STATUS = 0
```

[image: Simulation with different temperatures]

The simulation sensitivity study shows that there is an effect of temperature on the final objective. Using `T.STATUS=1` with different initial conditions also reveals that higher temperature gives a more optimal solution. The only effect of the initial condition is that it requires one or two steps to get up to the maximum allowable temperature.

[image: optimization solution]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO()

nt = 101
m.time = np.linspace(0,100,nt)

# Parameters
T = m.MV(value=321,ub=338,lb=298)
T.STATUS = 1
T.DCOST = 0 #0.01
T.DMAX = 20

# Variables
CTG = m.Var(value=0.3226)
CDG = m.Var(value=0)
CMG = m.Var(value=0)
CE = m.Var(value=0)
CA = m.Var(value=1.9356)
CG = m.Var(value=0)

p = np.zeros(nt)
p[-1] = 1.0
final = m.Param(value=p)

# Intermediates
k1 = m.Intermediate(3.92e7*m.exp(-6614.83/T))
k2 = m.Intermediate(5.77e5*m.exp(-4997.98/T))
k3 = m.Intermediate(5.88e12*m.exp(-9993.96/T))
k4 = m.Intermediate(0.98e10*m.exp(-7366.64/T))
k5 = m.Intermediate(5.35e3*m.exp(-3231.18/T))
k6 = m.Intermediate(2.15e4*m.exp(-4824.87/T))

# Equations
m.Equation(CTG.dt()== -k1*CTG*CA + k2*CDG*CE)
m.Equation(CDG.dt()== k1*CTG*CA - k2*CDG*CE - k3*CDG*CA + k4*CMG*CE)
m.Equation(CMG.dt()== k3*CDG*CA - k4*CMG*CE - k5*CMG*CA + k6*CG*CE)
m.Equation(CE.dt()== k1*CTG*CA - k2*CDG*CE + k3*CDG*CA - k4*CMG*CE + k5*CMG*CA - k6*CG*CE)
m.Equation(CA.dt()== -CE.dt())
m.Equation(CG.dt()== k5*CMG*CA - k6*CG*CE)

# Objective Function
m.Maximize(CE*final)

m.options.IMODE=6
m.options.NODES=3
m.options.SOLVER=3

plt.figure()
m.options.TIME_SHIFT=0
for Ti in [300,305,310,315,320,325,330,335]:
    T.value=Ti
    m.solve(disp=False)
    plt.subplot(2,1,1)
    plt.plot(m.time,CE.value,lw=2,label=r'$C_E$ @ $T_0$='+str(Ti))
    plt.subplot(2,1,2)
    plt.plot(m.time,T.value,lw=2,label=r'$T$ @ $T_0$='+str(Ti))
    print(Ti,'K Objective: ' + str(CE[-1]))

plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.xlabel('Time')

plt.show()
```

I would recommend that you feed in the optimal solution that comes from the publication as an initial guess to see if that improves the optimization result. There may be a difference in equations or objective function that gives the different results.